# How do I find the mappings between sedol and isin codes?

Tags: market-data

I am looking at data for Unit Trusts and OEICs in the UK.

They are identified by SEDOL or ISIN codes.

Given an SEDOL, how can I find the ISIN associated with the same product?  And given an ISIN, how can I find the associated SEDOL?

Answer (score 2):

Options:

- bloomberg terminal (if you have one or someone else at work does)
- Do you have the issuer names - could look around their websites where they typically list all reference names!